# Add link to statistics site for all user

Tags: wordpress

I want to display access statistics to all users of my site. I have a plugin in my site where i can explore statistic in my wordpress dashboard, but i want to display this informations for all user. Is there a statistics plugin that allows me to create a link to see the statistics (weekly users, most visited pages)? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin call [WP Statistics](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-statistics/) which is having an inbuilt feature to expose statistics data. Using the widget method, you can show information to your users mentioned in the image attachment.

[image]

Comment: This is how I'm showing in my web [page](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15rQzQLbBO1jhe_OHFJlsobKtryHvrPGi/view?usp=sharing)